# SQL html сущности

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

```
INSERT INTO `cgame`.`matches` (`match_id`, `dota_match_id`, `match_league_id`, `match_league_name`, `match_players`, `match_radiant_team`, `match_radiant`, `match_radiant_wins`, `match_dire_team`, `match_dire`, `match_dire_wins`) VALUES (NULL, '', '', '', '[{"account_id":292952329,"name":"FACEIT.com | DION Bot","hero_id":0,"team":4},{"account_id":171051127,"name":"PoziTiv","hero_id":68,"team":1},{"account_id":134507397,"name":"Shark^^","hero_id":22,"team":1},{"account_id":88571729,"name":"\u0427\u0435\u043f\u0443\u0448","hero_id":75,"team":1},{"account_id":123353281,"name":"Kappa \u263e","hero_id":84,"team":0},{"account_id":289037472,"name":"Penados","hero_id":99,"team":1},{"account_id":205631128,"name":"TOP MLG","hero_id":26,"team":0},{"account_id":253227109,"name":"kArt3r","hero_id":8,"team":1},{"account_id":129358159,"name":"\u0426\u043e\u043a \u0426\u043e\u043a","hero_id":25,"team":0},{"account_id":245405055,"name":"Solo 322 ><","hero_id":29,"team":0},{"account_id":302799649,"name":"n1k3","hero_id":18,"team":0}]', '', '', '', '', '', '')
```

Имею вот такой вот запрос, когда добавляю в таблицу слеш () перед сущностями пропадает соответственно выбрать их из строки затруднительно. Возможно как то корректное добавление сущности?

P.S. Когда добавляю через PMA все нормально добавляется, а когда запросом - слеш перед сущностями испаряется :D

Comment: приведите php код, с помощью которого вы делаете запрос, скорее всего проблема там

Comment: mysql при вставке интерпретирует обратные слеши, вам надо их удвоить. кроме того сам php интерпретирует слеши, которые жестко забиты у него в коде, тогда их обычно приходится учетверять